# Knockout.js: Using a jquery widget with knockout bindings inside HTML that is already knockout bound

Tags: knockout.js

I have a section of my page that is using knockout for the UI and calls ApplyBindings on that section aka:

#### HTML

```
<div id="example">
    <p data-bind="text: message"/>
    <i class="icon-information" title="some tooltip here"/>
</div>
```

#### JS

```
var model = createModel();
ko.applyBindings(model, $("#example")[0]);
```

and I have a widget that was created that also uses Knockout under the covers that I'd like to hook up to the `i` tag to get a nice tooltip. The problem is that because applyBindings basically gets called twice on the `i` tag there are errors. I understand that in the contrived example I could just move the `i` tag out of where my bindings are but in the real code this is simple not possible.

My question is how are people handling these types of situations? THe easiest answer is to change the widget to not use Knockout but that sucks and is a lot of extra code.

#### Please Don't focus solely on the demo code above. This is more of a theoretical example. Trying to use the real example would take too much explaining.

Comment: Can't you make the tooptip part of your model?

Comment: @llya I could but that would defeat the point of having a widget. I have the widget so that it can be reusable across my site. In fact I created the widget because I found myself copy and pasting the code multiple times throughout my site.

Comment: You can still write the code once and just add it to multiple models.

Comment: @llya no offense but you're not helping :) It's a widget and needs top stay a widget.

Comment: @Matthew you can reuse it, just have a global widgets hash and setup all of your models the same way, ie model.widgets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that there are a couple of options that you could pursue depending on the nature of your widget.

The first is to use the `ko.applyBindingsToNode` API rather than adding a "data-bind" attribute and calling `ko.applyBindings` from your widget.

You would call it like:

```
ko.applyBindingsToNode(element, { someBindings: val, anotherBinding: val2 });
```

It also accepts a third argument to pass the data context, which is used in control-flow scenarios.

Here is a sample that binds a separate observable using this API, then calls `ko.applyBindings` with the "normal" view model: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/QBMSB/. It certainly would be possible to add conflicting bindings in this way (two of the same binding against different values), so it would be something to use in a targeted way.

If you are doing something more like inserting a "template" (a bunch of HTML) and it is not necessarily convenient to call `ko.applyBindingsToNode` on each element, then you can use the technique described [here](http://www.knockmeout.net/2012/05/quick-tip-skip-binding.html) to prevent bindings from being applied to a child.

So, you would have a simple binding like:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.stopBinding = {
    init: function() {
        return { controlsDescendantBindings: true };
    }
};
```

Then, your widget would insert a wrapper element that contains this binding. You could then call applyBindings on the children and not worry that a "normal" applyBindings call would interfere.

Here is a sample with the widget markup just entered directly: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/Tf79p/.  My assumption would be that your widget would add markup like this when called.

Answer (score 0):

Re: the above comments, it does not defeat the point of having a widget.

Create a custom binding as an adapter between the tooltip widget and the model/viewmodel (depending on how you're doing the tooltip, or which tooltip widget you're using).  I'm using jQuery Tools' tooltips (http://jquerytools.org/documentation/tooltip/index.html) this way, all it took was creating a simple custom binding handler:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.jqTooltip = {
  init: function (element, valueAccessor) {
     var options = valueAccessor() || {};
     $(element).tooltip();
  }
}
```

then in your binding:

```
data-bind="jqTooltip:{}"
```

or something similar, passing options you need in the object and adjusting the custom handler to take in those options properly (above i did not do that).

This should not take a separate viewmodel, and note you can have lots of models in your viewmodel.  See tons of Ryan Niemeyer's examples (google it) with jqDialog, jqButton, and others.  For reuse, have it as a separate model properly namespaced and instantiate whenever you need it.

Comment: Yes I am doing something like this already I have wrote and blogged about a widget binding. http://blog.osbornm.com/2013/02/27/knockout-js-widget-binding/ The problem is that the widget I am using (a custom widget that I wrote for counting down time) uses Knockout itself. so inside the widget there is knockout binding happening to make the "countdown" code much simpler.

Comment: Ah I see.  Yeah in this case, there's no way that will work.  IMO I don't think you should let widgets be the basis of the root-level bindings. I like to always have a root-level wrapper that the bindings are applied to [eg, rather than something like $('.button'), i prefer $('#wrapper'), then data-bind what needs to be data-bound inside].  And apply the bindings to a viewmodel which can control all the various widgets/models.